# Replace Picture Source (Error Handling)

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a script wich changes the source of an image ie webpics/1.jpg to webpics/2.jpg on click of an image. One problem i am having though is that the script will still work for one more image after there is images, so if i have 11 images i can press next 11 times and will get an empty image, what i would like is for the script to run a error check and stay on the current image if the next on doesn't exist. Here is the script:

```
$("#prev, #next").click(function() { 
var currentNumber = parseInt($("#image1").attr("src").split('gallery/')[1]); // get the
number
var newNumber = ($(this).attr("id")=="next")?currentNumber+1:currentNumber-1;
var testImage = new Image();
testImage.onload=function() {
var img = $("#image1");
img.attr("src",this.src);
img.css("visibility","visible");   
}
testImage.onerror=function() {
$("#image1").css("visibility","hidden");   
} 
testImage.src="http://www.yogahealth.net.au/gallery/"+newNumber+".jpg";
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how many images exist? If so, just test if the new number would exceed the total count (`if newNumber ...`) and do nothing (i.e. skip the part where you change the `testImage.src`.

For example, you need to have the total count in the variable `totalImages`, then you could do:

```
$("#prev, #next").click(function() { 
  var currentNumber = parseInt($("#image1").attr("src").split('gallery/')[1]); // get the   number
  var newNumber = ($(this).attr("id")=="next")?currentNumber+1:currentNumber-1;
  var totalImages = // get the number of total images here
  if ((newNumber > totalImages) || (newNumber <= 0)) {
        return false; // just do nothing
  }

  // here comes the rest of your code
});
```

Note that I also added the possibility that your number becomes less than 0 or 0, depending on whether you have an image named `0`. If yes, you can change the `<=` to `<`, otherwise it won't show the `0` image.

In order to get this number into your Javascript code, you could either render the code using PHP and insert it into your script with `<?php echo $total; ?>` or you extract it from another element from the HTML page, as you did with the `currentNumber`.

Comment: @slhck I do know how many images exist. Where exactly are you suggesting i place the code and i would more then if newNumber ...

Comment: @slhck Just ended up doing <= etc 11, because i had 11 images.